# Opening QR reader in iPhone15

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, zxing.net

I am reading QR code through the below code.

```
ZXing.Result result = await scanner.Scan(new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions()
{
    AutoRotate = true,
}, true);
```

When I try to debug in iphone 15 (iOS 17.3.1), I get the following error. `"System.NotSupportedException: "humanFullBody" has no associated enum value on this platform.'"`

It works fine in iPhone 12 with the same iOS version and also in iPhone 15 simulator. I use Xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with the QR reader but an issue with the latest iPhone, some new flags were added to the Camera API and because of it you are facing this exception the fix was already added in .NET 8 but I am not sure if this will also be added into XF.

You can find more details on this here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18833

You could raise a bug for this with the XF team if you want, but I'm not sure if this will be addressed. May be being on the latest version of XF could help you!

Comment: XF -> Xamarin forms?

Comment: Yes, You could try this library if you don't mind switching to another and see if that has the same issue https://github.com/JimmyPun610/BarcodeScanner.Mobile

Comment: This doesn't work either.